# Can't seem to affect input element attribute inside of nested setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

http://jsfiddle.net/ZkAdt/8/

Take the URL: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B8c2G7RN0TM and paste it into the input field.

Observe the input field does not say "Thanks!" after pasting.

Check the logs. Observe that flashMessage fires, that self._input visually looks identical to that of the DOM element, but that the two are not the same.

Attempting to directly affect the DOM element does not work either.

What've I done horrible wrong?

Comment: It is the same element you have to compare with `var result = this._input[0] == $('#songUrlInput')[0];` otherwise you only check that you have two different jQuery objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is rather simple. It's just not so simple to debug on jsFiddle. You are setting the placeholder with this line:

```
this._input.attr('placeholder', message).val('').blur();
```

Additionally you trigger blur which fires your other event handler that sets the placeholder back to the default text.